# Вылетает приложение при отладке. Ругается на последнюю строчку (ButtonDay.setText(DayWeek);)

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button ButtonDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButtonDay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDay);

        Calendar data = new GregorianCalendar();
        Integer DayWeek = data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        ButtonDay.setText(DayWeek);


    }
}
```

Comment: А как ругается то? что в лог выводит?

Comment: ButtonDay.setText(""+DayWeek);

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А не можете объяснить зачем нужно ставить ковычки?